# Constantly changing 127.0.0.x addresses in azure compute emulator

Tags: azure, dns, localhost

I have a solution containing 3 azure web roles and 1 worker role.

These roles each have their own azure deployment project, because they need different subdomains and may have to be deployed independently.

While developing aspects that are url-sensitive (like cookies spanning multiple subdomains, inter-connectivity between roles, etc.), the ever-changing virtual IPs of the azure compute emulator (I currently have 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3 and 127.0.0.8 (nothing in-between) for some reason) became a problem. Additionally, since the browser would recognize each IP as a different host I would need dns addresses to implement subdomain-spanning cookies.

There does not seem to be a lot of information material about this topic, so maybe my approach is just wrong, but how do you others solve those cases?

1) Use full IIS instead of IIS Express. I don't know if that would be a viable solution, I guess it would stop the changing addresses, but I would prefer the lightweight IIS Express as long as possible. Additionally I am not sure if I could use stable subdomains (which are not the same as the production ones) w/o too much manual work.

2) Use the hostHeader attribute in the ServiceDefinition.csdef. Would only work with manual changes to the hosts file and I would not be able to reach the productive code without removing the hosts file entries (error-prone and just tedious)

3) Some form of reverse proxy, but that really feels like overkill.

I hope I'm just forgetting something obvious ;)

Regards, 
Pharao2k

[Edit]
All I want is to have my three projects debugging in parallel with consisting urls with either one hostname for all three or one dns name (with subdomains for each project). Maybe I lost my sanity while trying this, but I can't seem to figure out how this can be done.

- If I use IIS Express and three Azure deployment projects, each will get another IP (127.0.0.X) each time I press compile. Sure, I could edit my hosts file and refresh dns caches EVERY TIME I PRESS F5, but that's just not acceptable.
- If I use Full IIS and three Azure deployment projects, it won't let me start more than one at a time -> unusable.
- If I use a combined Azure project for all my roles then I'll have to maintain at least 5 azure projects ... the single ones (for real deployment, as I said, they have to be deployable independently) and the combined one. And I am pretty sure that this will kick me in the nuts somehow and this sure as hell can't be a tested scenario.
  *[Edit #2] wow, even here do the ip addresses change, so back to modifying hosts file + dns flush after every F5 -.-*

I can't imagine that my scenario of using subdomains is that unusual, I don't understand why no one else seems to be having this problem.

Comment: Try setting the pulic port on your web endpoints to a high number that won't have conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't help with changing ip addresses ;)

Comment: Ah, sorry you're right with all of them being different cloud projects.  If you the multiple web roles in a singe cloud development project it would work since it would be a single ip.

Comment: even then did the IP address (sometimes?) change, don't really know why

Comment: Depends on how you are getting it ip.  if you are getting it in you application it changes due to the load balancer, but the ip of the loadbalancer for that app should stay the same.  If you don't set to port number, then they tend to change if you start and stop the emulator very often.  I have 2 web roles and a worker in a single cloud project using higher ports like 8210, 8220, 8230 and things don't seem to change for me (or the other devs on the project)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest consolidating the Web Roles into a single role. You'll get an easier deployment to manage, better value of money (i.e. a smaller minimum deployment size) and a single dimension to scale.

You can use different port numbers or host headers to direct traffic to the correct endpoint.

There are plenty of articles available which describe how to do this, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately the different roles can't be consolidated into fewer roles, since they need to be deployment-independent. There has to be a way to host multiple hosts with dns addresses in the compute emulator.

Comment: Do you actually need the emulator? You can probably just run the web applications on IIS/cassini directly.

Comment: They would behave differently when not used in an azure context, would be very hard to test like that.

Comment: How would they behave differently? For testing, you should use the real infrastructure. The emulator has a number of differences.

Comment: While I do see your point...aren't role restarts, tracing, configuration via azure config files etc. all very different under full IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Bring up properties on each project (the reference project, not the Azure role project). Go to Project Properties -> Web. I checked "Use Local IIS server" and "Use IIS Express." To lock things down, I then set the URL I wanted in the Project URL.

I use http://localhost:[port number] but you should be able to configure the server and hosts file as needed once it stops picking random IPs and ports.

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if I wouldn't start the web roles via the azure compute emulator? While certainly possible, that would mean I couldn't locally test load balancing, diagnostics, tracing etc., at least not in the "azure way".